# How to remove 301 redirection from website

Tags: redirect

I'm using a WordPress site and from the day I have started my website. My website is creating HTTP redirect automatically for every post blog and single tags. I have run a test on a screaming frog and found 30 redirections from my website to the same content.
I have searched and watched various videos but sill my issues are unresolved.
Please help me to remove those redirections from my website.

Here is the .htaccess code of my website.

```html
# BEGIN LSCACHE
## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
<IfModule LiteSpeed>
RewriteEngine on
CacheLookup on
RewriteRule .* - [E=Cache-Control:no-autoflush]
### marker CACHE RESOURCE start ###
RewriteRule wp-content/.*/[^/]*(responsive|css|js|dynamic|loader|fonts)\.php - [E=cache-control:max-age=3600]
### marker CACHE RESOURCE end ###
### marker FAVICON start ###
RewriteRule favicon\.ico$ - [E=cache-control:max-age=86400]
### marker FAVICON end ###
### marker DROPQS start ###
CacheKeyModify -qs:fbclid
CacheKeyModify -qs:gclid
CacheKeyModify -qs:utm*
CacheKeyModify -qs:_ga
### marker DROPQS end ###
</IfModule>
## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
# END LSCACHE
# BEGIN NON_LSCACHE
## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
### marker BROWSER CACHE start ###
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresByType application/pdf A2592000
ExpiresByType image/x-icon A2592000
ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon A2592000
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A2592000
ExpiresByType image/jpg A2592000
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A2592000
ExpiresByType image/png A2592000
ExpiresByType image/gif A2592000
ExpiresByType image/webp A2592000
ExpiresByType video/ogg A2592000
ExpiresByType audio/ogg A2592000
ExpiresByType video/mp4 A2592000
ExpiresByType video/webm A2592000
ExpiresByType text/css A2592000
ExpiresByType text/javascript A2592000
ExpiresByType application/javascript A2592000
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A2592000
ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf A2592000
ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff A2592000
ExpiresByType application/font-woff A2592000
ExpiresByType application/font-woff2 A2592000
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject A2592000
ExpiresByType font/ttf A2592000
ExpiresByType font/woff A2592000
ExpiresByType font/woff2 A2592000
</IfModule>
### marker BROWSER CACHE end ###
## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
# END NON_LSCACHE
# Wordfence WAF
<IfModule LiteSpeed>
php_value auto_prepend_file '/home/u911584/domains/rgeek.in/public_html/wordfence-waf.php'
</IfModule>
<IfModule lsapi_module>
php_value auto_prepend_file '/home/u911584/domains/rgeek.in/public_html/wordfence-waf.php'
</IfModule>
# END Wordfence WAF
## Start Auto Login
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
## End Auto Login

# BEGIN rlrssslReallySimpleSSL rsssl_version[3.3.5]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} '"scheme":"http"'
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# END rlrssslReallySimpleSSL
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
# BEGIN ShortPixelWebp
# The directives (lines) between `BEGIN ShortPixelWebp` and `END ShortPixelWebp` are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
# END ShortPixelWebp
# DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE AND THE LINES BELLOW UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS:
Header always set Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests
# DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE AND THE LINES BELLOW UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS:
```

Comment: Redirections are usually specified in an .htaccess document located in the root folder of the site. Can you access this doc?

Comment: yes, I can access the .htaccess of my website. Please tell me how to remove this HTTP redirection is increasing day by day as I post any new blog it create a HTTP redirect for that.

Comment: Without seeing your htaccess file I wouldn't know which rule/s are to blame for the behaviour but as a general sort of guide, look at the URLs in rewrite rules or at 301 redirects. That should give you a clue.

Comment: I have added the code of my website.

Comment: Okay. What is the final URL of the redirect? Also is it always to the same page?

Comment: It looks like these for Example –
Address:  https://aaranyatech.com/redmi-smart-band-is-launching-in-india-on-september-8
Redirected to:  https://aaranyatech.com/redmi-smart-band-is-launching-in-india-on-september-8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your last comment the links you posted are almost the same except for a forward slash at the end. I think I can see the issue. Your HT access file has a duplicate function;

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
 </IfModule>

 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
 </IfModule>
```

This means 2 redirections are taking place for every index page link.
What I would do is comment out # both those blocks like this;

```
 # <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 # RewriteEngine On
 # RewriteBase /
 # RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 # RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
 # </IfModule>

 # <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 # RewriteEngine On
 # RewriteBase /
 # RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 # RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
 # </IfModule>
```

and add this which will remove all trailing slashes on every link;

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R]
 </IfModule>
```